# Instantiation of stateless objects in Java

Tags: java, static

Is there any way in Java to avoid instantiating a stateless object? There is no real difference between a static function and a stateless object for example:

```
class CompareInts {
  Integer compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
    return a.compareTo(b);
  }

static Integer compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
  return a.compareTo(b);
}
```

Functionality wise these two alternatives do the same thing and in general every stateless class can be converted to a static function. There are two main differences though:

1. Instantiating a static class takes both time and memory where neither are needed. You only really need to store the code you don't need to allocate an object on the heap and a pointer to a vtable.
2. static functions are very limited in Java. They can not be used with Generics, the static compare can never be used by a class that must receive a compare.

Therefore a static function is better in theory because it provides all the functionality of a stateless class but without the runtime and memory overheads. A static function is much less powerful in Java because it can't be called through a Generic type. Is there any way to benefit from both worlds?

**Edit**

I want to write a generic class as follows:

```
class Array<Type, Comparator> {
  Type[] elements;
  // array stuff

  Type getMax() {
    Type maxElement = Type.getSmallestLegalValue();
    for (Type element : elements) {
      maxElement = Comparator.compare(maxElement, element) > 0 ? maxElement : element;
    }
    return maxElement;
  }
}
```

I can't write this. I have to accept a `Comparator` in `Array`'s constructor and create a`Comparator` interface that `CompareInts` implements.

Comment: "A static function is much less powerful in Java because it can't be called through a Generic type."
...And what about `public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int compare(T first, T second) {
        return first.compareTo(second);
    }`?

Comment: Are you running out of memory due to stateless object creation (creating so many that you exhaust memory could indicate a design flaw)? Are compiler optimizations insufficient and are you taking a performance hit that you've narrowed down to instantiation of stateless objects (in which case have you considered other ways to express your code so that you can reuse such an object)? By the way you likely wish to make the class `static` as well so it doesn't require (or point to) a parent object.

Comment: You can utilize [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Comment: If it is a static method, why would you want to use a class wide generic type for it? That defeats the purpose of a static method. As sp00m answered, yes, you can use generics on static methods, but it limited to the method scope.

Comment: And next time, do your research better - check `java.util.Collections` for example, a whole lot of static *and* generic functions.

Comment: If in doubt, panic and use the Singleton pattern! Generics and Static methods is probably the way to go?

Comment: In Java 8 you have [Method References](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) which means that you *can* use the static compare in other classes (other classes methods).

Comment: You are mostly arguing with and resisting the answers below, and stating things like "this is not what I want" despite all of the answers below addressing your issue (or lack thereof). If the 6 answers below are not what you want, please edit your question to clearly state what it is that you are after. Please also do a bit more research before asking. As it stands it appears you came here only to argue. The answer to your question is: Use the stateless object, because it doesn't matter like you think it does, it's how this is done, and your code will be clear.

Comment: I guess the correct answer is that it is impossible. I have recently started programming in Java after many years in C++ and it surprised me that this very basic (and ubiquitous) feature would be non-existent in Java. It makes it impossible to write an efficient implementation of a collection that requires a Comparator. If you look at PriorityQueue you will see that it holds a pointer to a comparator. That is 8 bytes that are completely wasted (especially if the default comparator is fine). If you have one Queue than it is not too bad but if you have many small Queues it's a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an instance, just as you need a function in functional languages where functions are first class citizens.

But you don't need to create a new instance each time, you can store that instance in a static variable of your Comparator class.

Answer (score 2):

Generics can be used with static methods:

```
static <T extends Number & Comparable<T>> int compare(T a, T b) {
    return a.compareTo(b);
}
```

Comment: This is a generic static function. That is not what I want. I want a generic class to call its generic type's static function.

Comment: @BenjyKessler Then your examples aren't very representative ;) But whatever, this is not possible since class parameters belong to instances while static elements belong to class.

Comment: @BenjyKessler That would render the generic type pointless. A static function is bound to the type it is declared in. It cannot be overridden. So a generic type is not the way to go here.

Comment: Au contraire it would make the generic much more powerful. A static function is bound to a type and so is a generic argument. When you specify that you want and Array<Integer> you are binding your Array to the type Integer. If it weren't for type erasure we would be able to call static functions declared in Integer (e.g. GetMaxInteger).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe static method references is what you are looking for: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

E.g.:

```
return elements.stream().max(SomeComparator::someStaticCompareMethod);
```

Comment: That's a nice syntax shortcut but it doesn't really help the fact that there has to be an instance created of the Comparator. You still have a this pointer. Where there is not meaning to a this pointer in a stateless class.

Comment: @BenjyKessler You don't have to implement and instantiate a comparator. It's enough to provide a method which has the same signature (the name can be different). I don't know what happens behind the scene exactly but most likely some invokedynamic magic.

Answer (score -1):

Use the stateless objects.

If the object is stateless you'd never really need to allocate more than one, in theory (e.g. allocate a single static instance and reuse it). It is unlikely that you would ever use a significant amount of memory for such objects.

Your concerns about memory usage and instantiation time are nothing to worry about. In your example you're speaking of a couple of bytes and a few microseconds added to an entire sort operation -- It's completely negligible.

The passing of a `this` pointer to a method will be negligible as well, and I imagine the optimizer would take care of it anyways.

So, set your concerns aside and stick with clear, maintainable, easy-to-implement code. If you are having performance problems, profile, and I guarantee you will not find that your bottleneck is here.

Comment: you'd never really need to allocate more than one -> I don't  need to allocate any. There is no meaning to a this pointer there is no reason to create one and pass it to all function calls.

Comment: @BenjyKessler I was responding to your question... in your example you would need to allocate one. Also you wrote *"Instantiating a static class takes both time and memory where neither are needed."* You were concerned about time and memory taken when instantiating your stateless object. I addressed that directly.

Comment: Yes you addressed it by saying that memory and time are needed when instantiating stateless objects. I knew that.

Comment: @BenjyKessler *If the object is stateless you'd never really need to allocate more than one. It is unlikely that you would ever use a significant amount of memory for such objects.* I.e. your concerns about memory usage and instantiation time are unjustified, because you only need one. I.e. it's not a problem like you think it is.

Answer (score -1):

Having only a private zero-argument constructor prevents instantiation of a class.

E.g.:

```
public final class Sample {
    public static int method() {
        return 1;
    }

    private Sample() {
        // private to avoid instantiation
    }
}
```

It's good practice to then make the class final.

Comment: You'd probably also want to make the class itself `static`, since it doesn't really require an outer class to function, although it's kind of moot with the static method.

Comment: @JasonC This won't be possible if not enclosed within another class (*"Illegal modifier for the class ...; only public, abstract & final are permitted"*).

Comment: @sp00m Right; for some reason I'm assuming he's using an inner class. It must have been the lack of `public`, although I guess it could be a private top-level class.